Running Point-of-Sale on iOS 12
I have an iPhone 6 running iOS 12 that I would like to convert into a Point-of-Sale. I can install Loyverse and then use a separate card reader, but I wonder if the phone's NFC can convert the phone into a contactless card reader. I am in the UK and my banking providers are retail banks like HSBC and VirginMoney, or challenger banks like Monzo or Revolut. Is that possible?

I am surprised a vendor will support PCI and secure payment standards on an OS that is no longer receiving security updates. Who will your banking provider be and in which country are you doing business? Great question on the reader.

@bmike I edited the question with those details.

iPhone supports Tap to Pay on iOS 15.4 and later.
Developers of apps for payment service providers can implement Tap to Pay in their app using ProximityReader, or indirectly using a PSP's SDK. This would be able to be used for receiving payments in a supported region on compatible devices:

Tap To Pay - Regions & Providers - Apple Developer

Also see the original announcement on Tap To Pay - Apple Newsroom
A compatible version of iOS (at least iOS 15.4) can be installed on iPhone 6s or newer. It cannot be installed on iPhone 6: iOS 15 - Supported Devices (historical page on Apple Belarus).

I checked each item on the "Regions & providers" list. MyPOS and Viva start at iOS 13. None of them work on iOS 12.
